# discord py - Send a different message if a user replies to my bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to send a specific message if anyone replies to a message from my discord bot, I tried many things, but can't find a solution. Aside from that, it is new in 1.6 and I can't find it in the docs from discord. I found "reference" but don't understand how I can use that.

What I tried:

```
if len(message.replies) >= 0:
   await ctx.send('thanks for reply dude')
```

but sadly, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `message.replies`, it's `message.reference`

```py
if message.reference is not None:
    await ctx.send("Thanks for the reply dude")
```

```py
if message.reference is not None:
    if message.reference.cached_message is None:
        # Fetching the message
        channel = bot.get_channel(message.reference.channel_id)
        msg = await channel.fetch_message(message.reference.message_id)

    else:
        msg = message.reference.cached_message
```

Note that this still has some flaws, the `message_id` attribute can also be `None`

#### Reference:

- [`Message.reference`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reference)
- [`MessageReference.channel_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageReference.channel_id)
- [`MessageReference.messageid`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageReference.message_id)

Comment: But wouldn't that still occur to messages like "message was pinned" or something? I read that

Comment: And small other question, how can i get the message.content from the replied message?

Comment: I'm unsure what about the first question, but you can check out the edit

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9VHqPXrR - doesn't work. What am I'm making wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What's happening?Any errors?

Comment: No errors and "msg_reply.content" is empty.